# Can we show Facebook permission Dialog Directly(my app is already authorized)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication

Basically I want to **check the extended permissions** the user has granted my app.
If any one permission that I want is not given by the user, Then **I want the user to be redirected to facebook permission Dialog(Not the oauth dialog which comes first)**.
Is it possible to do that using php or js sdk(**php preferred**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then I want the user to be redirected to facebook permission Dialog(Not the oauth dialog which comes first).

First of all, there’s a misunderstanding on your side here: That **is** only **one** dialog, it’s only split into two pages where appropriate.

So when asking for (more) extended permissions, you just call the OAuth dialog the *normal* way (getLoginURL in PHP SDK, FB.login from the JS SDK) – if the user has already authorized your app and only new extended permissions are required, then only the second page of the dialog is shown automatically.